# Hide contents of drop-down list in Excel with password?

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu, password-protection, dropdownlistview

I'm trying to hide drop-down list items with a password in excel. Currently a password must be entered to make the selection, but you can still see all choices of the drop down by simply clicking in the cell w/o a pwd.

I essentially want to mask those items so they're only visible to users who have the password.

Data Validation w/ protected sheet and in-cell dropdown

Comment: So use a second range with an if() to reference the source if the password is correct or even test the password and multiply if true.

Answer (score 0):

So, 3 versions all relatively similar:

[image]

Above shown with thew correct password entered.

Below without:

[image]

Now with a range with Data validation, with and without password:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if the password is a prompt (Unlock Range) vs text in a cell, how would i grab the password entered?

Comment: vba can use the name defined on the sheet. Do you have any code as you don't tag vba for your question.

Comment: no, not using vba for this portion/these two cells. I just need to find a way to call the password. So you're saying I can use 'Worksheet.Protect'?

Comment: @drea24c I defined a name "password" and showed it in use.

Comment: what formula do you have in K3? I'm getting an error

Comment: @drea24c k3 is data validation ie the drop down.